# kafka-topics.sh ---delete --topic ''testTopic'' is not working for kafka V 0.10.1

Tags: apache-kafka

I try to delete a existing topic (I checked using kafka management console) using following command;

***#./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeper.xx.com:2181/chroot --delete --topic testTopic***

But it says topic not available in zookeeper.[1]

I create those topics at runtime . (I use Highlevel Client APIs.I think it is created in kafka clusters? )

How can I delete the topic using this bash script?

[1]

```
Error while executing topic command : Topic targettopic does not exist on ZK path zookeeper.xx.com:2181/chroot

[2016-10-14 11:58:59,919] ERROR java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Topic streamtargettopic does not exist on ZK path zookeeper.xx.com:2181/chroot

at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.deleteTopic(TopicCommand.scala:169)

at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:69)

at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

Comment: Does the topic exist? `./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181/chroot --topic testTopci --describe`

Comment: @louxiu No output for the above command. Means my topic is not in zookeeper? So, where the topics are created in kafka 0.10?

Comment: Not sure for 0.10.1, I tried this in 0.9.0.1 `./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --topic test_kafka123 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1`. The topic is under `/brokers/topics` in zk and command above can be printed. I think you can try to create topic using command if you have not tried.

Comment: @louxiu Issue was I had "/chroot" at the end of the zookeeper parameter. Now working fine without that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use below command to check the `list of topics` available in `Zookeeper`.

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

Also set the below properties in `server.properties`

```
delete.topic.enable=true
```

Then try to delete the topic using

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic test
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. Issue was i had "/chroot" at the end. That is how mentioned in the documentation http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_modify_topic

Comment: in latest version `--zookeeper` is replaced by `--bootstrap-server`. by changing it, this works for me only .

Answer (score 1):

If the below command didn't work for you

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic test
```

You can do the delete manually by connecting to zookeeper and delete the path.

```
./zookeeper-shell.sh
```

Manually delete the topic

```
rmr /brokers/topics/<topic>
```

Comment: this is deprecated