# List all Kafka 0.10 topics using - -zookeeper flag without access to Zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm using ***kafka 0.10*** without *zookeeper*. I want to get kafka topics list. This command is not working since we're not using zookeeper: 
`bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181`. How can I get the same output without zookeeper?

Comment: ```/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181```

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Kafka uses ZooKeeper so you need to first start a ZooKeeper server if you don't already have one.

If you do not want to install and have a separate zookeeper server, you can use the convenience script packaged with kafka to get a quick-and-dirty single-node ZooKeeper instance.

**Starting the single-node Zookeeper instance:**

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

**Starting the Kafka Server:**

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

**Listing the Topics available in Kafka:**

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

Comment: I need a solution without zookeeper. Is there any other command than this to list all topics without zookeeper?

Comment: I don't think its possible to even use kafka without zookeeper as the state of kafka is stored in zookeeper. How were you able to achieve it ?

Comment: If you are looking for a command to do it then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40034074/kafka-topics-sh-delete-topic-testtopic-is-not-working-for-kafka-v-0-10

Comment: If your zookeeper server is a named host, you'll need to give the host name instead of `localhost` e.g. `./kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper zookeeper:2181`. Or depending on your configuration you may need to use the IP address e.g. `./kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper 10.10.10.180:2181`

Comment: You can find more details here https://reachmnadeem.wordpress.com/2020/08/30/kafka-2-6-up-and-running-in-windows-10/

Comment: If you are on windows, use `bin/windows` instead of `bin`

Answer (score 64):

**Kafka 2.2 and up**

Newer versions of Kafka no longer requires ZooKeeper connection string to list topics, but can directly go via the Kafka brokers. `kafka-topics.sh` is provided in the `bin/` folder when downloading Kafka. To list topics, do the following:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server <BROKER-LIST>
```

Comment: assuming the OP meant "without the zookeeper cli option" - which is likely, since kafka doesn't work without zookeeper - this answer should be the accepted answer for Kafka 2.2+. The cli docs now indicate that --zookeeper is deprecated in favor of --bootstrap-server.

Comment: This is actually the best way to do it if you're working in AWS with their MSK. Otherwise you need to open up your ZooKeeper service, which can be a potential security issue if done incorrectly.

Comment: @MichaelRobinson granted that you use MSK with v2.2.1 and not v1.1.1.

Comment: Yes, my comment was localised to this post.

Comment: this must be the accepted answer as of 2022

Answer (score 31):

For dockerized kafka/zookeeper

```
docker ps
```

find you zookeeper container id

```
docker exec -it <id> bash

cd bin

./zkCli.sh

ls /brokers/topics
```

Comment: `./zkCli.sh` does not exists... in the zookeeper docker image

Answer (score 20):

to see that topic if we run the list topic command:

`$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181`

To check if the data is landing in Kafka:

`$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic twitterstream --from-beginning`

Answer (score 20):

We can use the following command:

```
kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

to list down all topics

Answer (score 7):

Commands:

To start the kafka:

```
 $ nohup ~/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh ~/kafka/config/server.properties > ~/kafka/kafka.log 2>&1 &
```

To list out all the topic on on kafka:

```
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh  --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

To check the data is landing on kafka topic and to print it out:

```
$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic your_topic_name --from-beginning
```

Answer (score 4):

Kafka requires zookeeper and indeed the list of topics is stored there, hence the kafka-topics tool needs to connect to zookeeper too.
kafka-clients apis in the newer versions no longer talk to zookeeper *directly*, perhaps that's why you're under the impression a setup without zookeeper is possible. **It is not**, as kafka relies on it internally. For reference see:
http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart
Step 2:

> Kafka uses ZooKeeper so you need to first start a ZooKeeper server if you don't already have one

Answer (score 4):

Using [Confluent's REST Proxy](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest) API:

```sh
curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" localhost:8082/topics
```

where `localhost:8082` is Kafka Proxy address.

Answer (score 4):

The `--zookeeper` is no longer a recognized option in version `3.1.0`

Hence, we can use

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

or

```
curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" localhost:9092/topics
```

to get the topics per broker level

Answer (score 3):

The Kafka clients no longer require zookeeper but the Kafka servers do need it to operate.

You can get a list of topics with the new AdminClient API but the shell command that ship with Kafka have not yet been rewritten to use this new API.

The other way to use Kafka without Zookeeper is to use a SaaS Kafka-as-a-Service provider such as Confluent Cloud so you don’t see or operate the Kafka brokers (and the required backend Zookeeper ensemble).

For example on Confluent Cloud you would just use the following zookeeper free CLI command:

```
ccloud topic list
```

Answer (score 2):

To read messages you should use:

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka1:9092,kafka2:9092,kafka3:9092 --topic messages --from-beginning
```

`--bootstrap-server` is required attribute.
You can use only single `kafka1:9092` node.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka is a distributed system and needs Zookeeper.
you have to start zookeeper too. 
Follow "Quick Start" here : https://kafka.apache.org/0100/documentation.html#quickstart

Answer (score 1):

Zookeeper is required for running Kafka. zookeeper is must. still if you want to see topic list without zookeeper then you need kafka monitoring tool such as Kafka Monitor Tool, kafka-manager etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the zookeeper server first.
So first go to kafka/bin/windows and run

```
zookeeper-server-start.bat ../../config/zookeeper.properties
```

then in the same folder with a new cmd windows start the kafka servers by running

```
kafka-server-start.bat ../../config/server.properties
```

> Note: if you starting it for the first time then there are certain
>   changes to be made in these files

**then inside kafka/bin/windows run**

```
kafka-topics.bat --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list
```

**to list down all the topics existing.**

Answer (score 0):

You have a stale version of the package with commands that no longer accept zookeeper but rather bootstrap-server as the connection. Confluent will then connect with Zookeeper internally.

https://www.confluent.io/download/ (5.3 or greater)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the below two command and list all Kafka topic

```
 - bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper 192.168.0.142:2181,192.168.9.115:2181,192.168.4.57:2181

- bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 192.168.0.142:2181,192.168.9.115:2181,192.168.4.57:218 --list
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I was having issues with the `--zookeeper` flag.

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-topics.bat --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

For linux or mac platform look for kafka-topics.sh file and then run