# How to view kafka topics running on a different server

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I would like to view all the topics running on a server from my local kafka scripts. I can view the details of a topic like this:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server <someip>:<somport> --topic  
mytopic --from-beginning
```

But can't find out a way to view all the topics running on `<someip>:<someport>`. Do I need to have a local instance of zookeeper running in order to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List all kafka topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405663/list-all-kafka-topics)

Comment: This views the mesages, not the "topic details". That woud require `kafka-topics --describe`

Comment: I dont think it is duplicate of that, it is helpful to have this separate

Answer (score 1):

If i understand the question correctly you can just use:

```
kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper remote-zookeeper:2181
```

and replace the ip and port in the command above. it is as simple as this assuming that the kafka cluster does not require authentication - authorization etc

Comment: the ip and port in my `kafka-console-consumer.sh` is for one of the kafka nodes. not for the zookeeper. For the `kafka-topics.sh` do I need ip and port for zookeeper running on the server??

Comment: @Anthony: Yes, `kafka-topics.sh` needs to communicate with the zookeeper at the moment to list the topics. This reliance on ZK is being addressed with [KIP-377](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-377%3A+TopicCommand+to+use+AdminClient)